# How to SELECT value of the column WHEN EXIST

Tags: mysql

I try to find a way to retrieve the text of a specific column when existing otherwise return 'NONE', here my query :

```
SELECT 
  t_operation.*, 
  CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT OperationID FROM t_operationtag
    WHERE t_operationtag.ElementID = t_operation.OperationID
    and t_operationtag.Property = "Category"
    and t_operation.Name LIKE CONCAT("%", "class", "%"))
  THEN 'FOUND'
  ELSE 'NONE'
  END AS TagValue  
FROM t_operation
```

Instead of 'FOUND' I would like to retrieve the value, like following (but this didn't work):

```
SELECT 
  t_operation.*, 
  CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT OperationID FROM t_operationtag
    WHERE t_operationtag.ElementID = t_operation.OperationID
    and t_operationtag.Property = "Category"
    and t_operation.Name LIKE CONCAT("%", "class", "%"))
  THEN t_operationtag.VALUE
  ELSE 'NONE'
  END AS NewFiled  
FROM t_operation
```

I opened an dbfiddle to try the query :
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ba10216a0979f0cc8adc16b4a867a05b

Thanks
Yan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t_operation.*, 
       COALESCE( (SELECT OperationID 
                  FROM t_operationtag
                  WHERE t_operationtag.ElementID = t_operation.OperationID
                    and t_operationtag.Property = "Category"
                    and t_operation.Name LIKE CONCAT("%", "class", "%")
                  LIMIT 1), 'NONE' ) AS TagValue  
FROM t_operation
```

Comment: Ok perfect ! Thank you but I Select VALUE instead of OperationID

Comment: @YanDEJAGER No problems to select another field. The only possible problem is when the subquery returns more than 1 record. In this case you must add ORDER BY into the subquery for to make the valuee selection deterministic.